# Logic WooCommerce URL

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce and my shoppage is called webshop.
If I go to this pages the URL is **https://www.example.com/webshop**

This page contains the categories and If I click on a categorie the URL is a little bit strange **https://www.example.com/product-categorie/thecategory/**

Is this normal? In my opinion it should be **https://www.example.com/webshop/thecategory/**

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is because of the WordPress URL structure. It is totally fine. But you can also change them by changing the permalink structure.
for changing the permalink:

1. Goto Settings
2. Choose Permalink.
3. Choose what you want (Post Name is good to go).